# Right syntax for extrapolating a variable with javascript template literals?

Tags: javascript, template-literals, extrapolation

Could somebody please point me in the right direction regarding the correct syntax of template literals ?

I have the following code (without template literals, works just fine) :

```
const dbUrl = 'localhost:27017/imgManager';
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Now I'd like to put `useNewUrlParser: true` in a variable :

```
const dbUrl = 'localhost:27017/imgManager',
      dbOptions = 'useNewUrlParser: true';
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + dbUrl, { dbOptions });
```

Doesn't work of course, `mongoose.connect()` complains it has no `dbOptions` :

```
$ node server.js 
Server up: http://localhost:3300
the options [dbOptions] is not supported
```

I guess template literals are the way to go, but what's the right syntax ? I tried the following, but none works :

```
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + dbUrl, { ${dbOptions} });`
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbUrl}, { ${dbOptions} }`);
mongoose.connect(`mongodb:\/\/${dbUrl}, { ${dbOptions} }`);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you want to have all the parameters as a *single string* and somehow expect the method to read that string and interpret what the parameters are?

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - I don't think your query has anything to do with template literals, nor is the solution to use them. If you want to store the `dbOptions` as a variable, you'd do `dbOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true }` and then call `mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + dbUrl, dbOptions);`

Comment: Template literals are used to create *text*, not *code*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template literals are only for strings, not objects. `dbOptions` should be an object, not a string.

```
const dbOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true };
```

Then you use the variable itself:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + dbUrl, dbOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works fine !

Answer (score 1):

Template literals don't work in arbitrary position, and they don't create arbitrary JS syntax. (Without a tag) they create strings only, and only a single value never two arguments at once. As options, you need to pass an object:

```
const dbUrl = 'localhost:27017/imgManager',
      dbOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true };
mongoose.connect(
   `mongodb://${ dbUrl }`, // first argument
    dbOptions // second argument
);
```

If you really get the options as a string, you would need to parse them into an object, e.g.:

```
const dbUrl = 'localhost:27017/imgManager',
      dbOptions = '"useNewUrlParser": true';
mongoose.connect(
   `mongodb://${ dbUrl }`, // first argument
    JSON.parse(`{${ dbOptions }}`) // second argument. The string is '{' + dbOptions + '}'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As `dbOptions` is a string in your approach, this `{ dbOptions }` is creating a js object as follow:

```
// cause that mongoose is complaining because it's not expecting 
// options with property name dbOptions
{ dbOptions: 'useNewUrlParser: true' }
```

You should do the following

```
const dbUrl = 'localhost:27017/imgManager',
      dbOptions = {useNewUrlParser: 'true'};    

// `mongodb://${dbUrl}` will generate the following string:
//  "mongodb://localhost:27017/imgManager" 
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbUrl}`, dbOptions);
```

Comment: Surely `dbOptions` should be an object, `{ useNewUrlParser: true}`